# SQL Grouping and Totals

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

My SQL guy is on a long vacation. I know enough to be dangerous. I have tables that when joined will give me various locations broken down by an Area and District and potential money and captured money. Columns of interest are Area/District/Potential/Realized. Roughly 12 top level Areas and 80 Districts within those Areas

How can I query the data such that I get a break on each change of District with its Potential total and Realized total along with the same Potential Total and District Total at the change of each Area?

Something like:

```
Area1     District1     500    200
Area1     District1     200    null
Total Row               700    200
Area1     District2     200    200
Area1     District2     null   null
Total Row               200    200
Area Total              900    400
Area2     District3......etc.........
```

EDIT for code. Here is what I have so far if I could get a total every time the AreaID or DistrictID changes I think I can get the rest

```
DECLARE @FiscalYear INT 
SELECT  @FiscalYear = 2014

SELECT     tblFacilities.FacilityID, 
        tblAreas.AreaID,
        tblFacilities.DistrictID, 
        tblFacilities.UnitName, 
        tblDistricts.DistrictName, 
        tblAreas.AreaName,
        TotalSavings = (SELECT TotalSavings FROM ufn_RainbowTCReductionStrategies(tblFacilities.FacilityID, @FiscalYear))

FROM       tblFacilities INNER JOIN tblDistricts ON tblFacilities.DistrictID = tblDistricts.DistrictID 
        INNER JOIN tblAreas ON tblDistricts.AreaID = tblAreas.AreaID
```

Comment: I like the *know enough to be dangerous* :-) Please provide your table's structure and some sample data. The things you could search for are `GROUP BY ` and `SUM` or `AVG` or any other aggregate function...

Comment: have you tried using GROUP BY ROLLUP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Area,
    District,
    SUM(Potential),
    SUM(Realized)
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    Area,
    District
WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: The `WITH ROLLUP` syntax is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx).  You should use the ANSI standard `GROUP BY ROLLUP(Area, District)` instead.